# How to get all Windows service names starting with a common word?

Tags: command-line, windows-services, command, command-prompt

There are some windows services hosted whose display name starts with a common name (here NATION). For example:

- NATION-CITY
- NATION-STATE
- NATION-Village

Is there some command to get all the services like 'NATION-'. Finally I need to stop, start and  restart such services using the command promt.

Comment: Powershell is installed in your machine ? Server or Workstation? SO ?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

```
sc queryex type= service state= all | find /i "NATION"
```

- use `/i` for case insensitive search
- the white space after `type=`is deliberate and required

Comment: btw, the find is case sensitive, to do a better search, use find /i "Nation" 
http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/find.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: remember to use the spaces after type= and state=, I didn't :(

Comment: Note that find will search on service names and also display names - To Filter just service names: `sc queryex type= service state= all | find /i "SERVICE_NAME: NATION"`;).

Comment: `sc` might be shorthand for `Set-Content`. Use `sc.exe` if this is the case

Comment: Awesome. Coming from Linux the Windows cmd line landscape makes no sense so it's all magic sauce.

Comment: Is there any way to see the services exe paths?

Answer (score 28):

Using [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), you can use the following

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.displayName.StartsWith("NATION-")} | Select name
```

This will show a list off all services which displayname starts with "NATION-".

You can also directly stop or start the services;

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.displayName.StartsWith("NATION-")} | Stop-Service
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.displayName.StartsWith("NATION-")} | Start-Service
```

or simply

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.displayName.StartsWith("NATION-")} | Restart-Service
```

Comment: Thanks Wimmel for the reply, but instead of shell scripting i am searching to create a simple .cmd file . some command  like SC STOP SERVICE_STARTS_WITH("NATION-")

Comment: [code]Get-Service -Name *NATION-*[/code]  is simpler and better!

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it, if you don't like the old PowerShell version.

```
# Create an array of all services running
$GetService = get-service
    
# Iterate throw each service on a host
foreach ($Service in $GetService)
{
    # Get all services starting with "MHS"
    if ($Service.DisplayName.StartsWith("MHS"))
    {
        # Show status of each service
        Write-Host ($Service.DisplayName, $Service.Status, $Service.StartType) -Separator "`t`t`t`t`t|`t"
        
        # Check if a service is service is RUNNING.  
        # Restart all "Automatic" services that currently stopped
        if ($Service.StartType -eq 'Automatic' -and $Service.status -eq 'Stopped' )
        {
            Restart-Service -Name $Service.DisplayName
            Write-Host $Service.DisplayName "|`thas been restarted!"   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Save it as a .ps1 file and then execute

`powershell -file "path\to your\start stop nation service command file.ps1"`